# Do voltage-gated channels in a neuron use ATP

Tags: proteins, neurophysiology, neuron

I have a question about action potentials in a neuron.

Do voltage-gated sodium and potassium channels use ATP? I mean when they are closed or when they want to open the gate, do they use ATP?

Answer (score 1):

No, they change conformation in response to voltage. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage-gated_ion_channel) has some general discussion of the gating process, as would any basic neuroscience textbook.

The primary energy (ATP) cost of neurotransmission is in establishing ion concentration gradients, via the [sodium/potassium ATPase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Na%2B/K%2B-ATPase). You can think of this as a special case of [secondary active transport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_transport), where the energy costs are in establishing a gradient that is then used for a later process which does not cost any direct energy.

Answer (score -1):

Learning and memory (synaptic weight matrices) are mediated, in part, by the concentration of voltage-gated sodium channels at the neuron’s axon initial segment. The more voltage-gated sodium channels, the more efficacious is the transformation of a neuron’s collective synaptic input potentials into output action potentials. Those voltage-gated sodium channels, dendritic spines, ion gradients, and synapses are continually be built up and broken down depending on the learning needs of the animal. While it is true that the Na, K, and Ca flow down electrochemical gradients when depolarization opens up the voltage-gated ion channels (and don’t use much ATP/energy at that instant), there is an immense expenditure of ATP/energy in the prefatory synthesis of protein, degradation of protein, and pumping ions against electrochemical gradients in order to establish the membrane potentials in the first place. Source: Lou, L. “Principles of Neurobiology” Chapter 10

Comment: It's typically ligand-gated channels that change concentration with learning and memory. Voltage-gated channels at the axon initial segment can regulate the transfer function, yes, but this affects all inputs to a cell rather than affecting them directly. In any case, this seems mostly irrelevant to the question asked.